# Windows Forms: form resized after changing screen resolution

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, svn, windows-7

After I changed screen resolution to 125% on my new development machine with Windows 7, Visual Studio changes a whole bunch of lines in auto-generated files, such as  MainForm.designer.cs. The changes occur every time I open the designer view of the form, so I have to revert them manually in SVN. Anyone knows how to prevent Visual Studio from making these unwanted changes?

Comment: Happens to me too (I use VS 2012) :(